# I am unable to set a label in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm just trying to test out the custom cell by have all the cells in the table say "Hi", but it won't work... the cells are all blank. It seems that the TheCell class is called before I can set the label text... I don't know how else to do it.

**TheCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TheCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *arrivalLabel;

@end
```

**TheCell.m**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        self.arrivalLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30);
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.arrivalLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"anIdentifier";

    TheCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[TheCell alloc] init];
    cell.arrivalLabel.text = @"hi";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is your `TheCell` all done in code or through a xib?

Comment: It is all done programmatically... I'm trying not to use xib or storyboard.

Comment: your label is created in TheCell's init ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues. You are calling the `init` method of your cell class. You should be calling the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method instead.

You should also only allocate the cell if the call to `dequeue...` returns `nil`.

Then you need to make sure that your cell's `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method is creating the label instance for the `arrivalLabel` property.

```
TheCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[TheCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.arrivalLabel.text = @"hi";
```

The other big problem is in your cell's `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method. You never create the label.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        _arrivalLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_arrivalLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: The cells are still showing up blank... I tried to add `self.arrivalLabel.text = @"TEST";` to `TheCell.m` and it still wouldn't show up.

Comment: No, the setting of the text is where it should be. Update your question with the code for your `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method.

Comment: I already have that methods code in the question... I haven't changed it. BTW, thanks for the help!

Comment: Oops - that you do. That's the problem. You never create the label for `arrivalLabel`.

Comment: I created it in the .h file for TheCell `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *arrivalLabel;`... do i need to create it again in the method?

Comment: Two things: 1) Don't make it an `IBOutlet` since you are doing this in code. 2) The property doesn't actually allocate an instance. You still need to call `alloc`init...` to create the actual instance accessed by the property.

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct:

```
TheCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[TheCell alloc] init];
```

You have to do something like:

```
TheCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[TheCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: The cells are still showing up blank... I tried to add `self.arrivalLabel.text = @"TEST";` to `TheCell.m` and it still wouldn't show up.